# class aggregation (classes within classes) with Python 3 and Tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

It says that base_obj is not defined. But I did define it already. So why am I getting this error?

here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self,an_int,a_string):
       self.the_int = an_int
       self.the_string = a_string

class BiggerClass:
    def __init__(self,an_instance_of_BaseClass,big_class_string,big_class_int,new_name):
        self.the_instance_of_BaseClass = an_instance_of_BaseClass   #here we are aggregating the base class into the bigger class
        self.the_big_class_string = big_class_string
        self.the_big_class_int = big_class_int
        self.the_big_class_new_name = new_name

base_int_var = IntVar()
base_string_var = StringVar()

bigger_name_var = StringVar()

entry_base_int = Entry(root,textvariable = base_int_var).pack()
entry_base_string = Entry(root,textvariable = base_string_var).pack()

big_new_name_var = StringVar()
entry_bigger_name = Entry(root, textvariable = bigger_name_var).pack()
entry_big_new_name = Entry(root,textvariable = big_new_name_var).pack()

def create_base_class_instance():
    global base_obj
    base_obj = BaseClass(base_int_var.get(),base_string_var.get())  # I define 'base_obj' here

list_of_bigs = []

def create_bigger_class_instance(big_handle):
    bigger_name_var = big_handle
    big_handle = BiggerClass(base_obj,bigger_name_var.get(),55,big_new_name_var.get())
    list_of_bigs.append(big_handle)
    #global big_obj
    #big_obj = BiggerClass(base_obj,bigger_name_var.get(),45)

create_base_class_button = Button(root, text ="create base class", command = create_base_class_instance).pack()
create_big_class_button = Button(root, text ="create big class", command = create_bigger_class_instance(big_new_name_var)).pack()

match_name_var = StringVar()
entry_match_name = Entry(root,textvariable = match_name_var).pack()

def my_button_method():
    for a_big in list_of_bigs:
        if a_big.the_big_class_new_name == match_name_var:
            print(a_big.the_instance_of_BaseClass.the_string)

   #print(big_obj.the_instance_of_BaseClass.the_int)

#bigger_class_obj = BiggerClass(base_obj,"hello this is the big class",45)
button_print_out = Button(root,text = "press me", command = my_button_method).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TOTTY/PycharmProjects/my game/aggregation practice fork 1.py", line 45, in <module>
    create_big_class_button = Button(root, text ="create big class", command = create_bigger_class_instance(big_new_name_var)).pack()
  File "C:/Users/TOTTY/PycharmProjects/my game/aggregation practice fork 1.py", line 39, in create_bigger_class_instance
    big_handle = BiggerClass(base_obj,bigger_name_var.get(),55,big_new_name_var.get())
NameError: name 'base_obj' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the object in create_base_class_instance function and you are calling it in my_button_method.

You should initialize it outside, and use global keyword in both functions.

However using global variables considered code smell. I would advise finding another solution, for example passing base_obj as an argument to both functions.

```
base_obj = None

def some_function():
    global base_obj
    # some code referencing base_obj

def other_function():
    global base_obj
    # some code referencing base_obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of code:

```
create_big_class_button = Button(..., command = create_bigger_class_instance(big_new_name_var)).pack()
```

You are immediately calling `create_bigger_class_instance(...)`, and the result of that is getting assigned to the command. Since `create_bigger_class_instance` relies on the existence of `base_obj`, and you haven't created `base_obj` yet since it's tied to a button click, you get the error.

(As a side note, doing something like `create_big_class_button = Button(...).pack()` will always result in `create_big_class_button` being set to `None`, because that is what `pack()` returns.)

Answer (score 0):

Functions in Python are executed only when they are called. The keyword `global` is used to indicate that the variable used here is the same as in the global scope. Thus you will need to add a declaring statement in the main class and not in any of the sub function.

For e.g. You will have to write

```
base_obj = None
```

In the main class before either of the two functions is called. You do not need  `global base_obj` in your second function as you are not assigning any value to it.